# Unserialize() Error Can't convert to string

Tags: php, serialization

When I try that line:

```
unserialize($_SESSION['user']);
```

I'm getting this error: Object of class user could not be converted to string

When I echo the session I get:

```
O:4:"user":7:{s:9:"accountId";s:1:"2";s:9:"firstName";s:12:"Ronald";s:8:"lastName";s:5:"Test";s:5:"email";s:22:"blabla@hotmail.com";s:10:"postalCode";s:7:"J0L 8G0";s:8:"username";s:12:"testuser";s:4:"role";s:1:"0";}
```

That is the class for user:

```
class user {
var $accountId;
var $firstName;
var $lastName;
var $email;
var $postalCode;
var $username;
var $role;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAccountId()
{
    return $this->accountId;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $accountId
 */
public function setAccountId($accountId)
{
    $this->accountId = $accountId;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $firstName
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->lastName;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $lastName
 */
public function setLastName($lastName)
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $email
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPostalCode()
{
    return $this->postalCode;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $postalCode
 */
public function setPostalCode($postalCode)
{
    $this->postalCode = $postalCode;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $username
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getRole()
{
    return $this->role;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $role
 */
public function setRole($role)
{
    $this->role = $role;
}

function __construct($accountId,$firstName,$lastName,$email,$postalCode,$username,$role){
    $this->setAccountId($accountId);
    $this->setFirstName($firstName);
    $this->setLastName($lastName);
    $this->setEmail($email);
    $this->setPostalCode($postalCode);
    $this->setUsername($username);
    $this->setRole($role);
}
```

}

This is where I create the object:

```
public function createUserObject($username){
    session_start();
    require("user.php");
    include("connection.php");
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

    mysql_connect("$SQLhost", "$SQLusername", "$SQLpassword") or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$SQLdb_name") or die("cannot select DB");

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Account WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $user = new user($rows['accountId'],$rows['firstName'],$rows['lastName'],$rows['email'],$rows['postalCode'],$rows['username'],$rows['role']);
    $_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);

    if($result){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks if somebody could explain me the issue.

Comment: That does not seem a valid serialized string. Can you do a `var_dump($_SESSION['user']);` and post the result here?

Comment: string(230) "O:4:"user":7:{s:9:"accountId";s:1:"2";s:9:"firstName";s:12:"Ronald";s:8:"lastName";s:5:"Test";s:5:"email";s:22:blablajtest@hotmail.com";s:10:"postalCode";s:7:"H0L 8G0";s:8:"username";s:12:"testuser";s:4:"role";s:1:"0";}"

Comment: Please post the relevant context surrounding the unserialize call. I appreciate that you strive for brevity, but in this case we do need a few extra lines to discern the error.

Comment: I added more lines of code.

Comment: That looks to me like it should work. I'm sorry I can't help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathieu, this is a known issue. Hence it would be good if you can modify your code a little bit.

Refer the following post for some idea: http://blog.pagalhost.com/codeigniter-php-serialize-unserialize-issues/

Hence what you need to do is something like the following way

```
//To serialize
$result_string = base64_encode(serialize($array));

//To unserialize
$restored_array = unserialize(base64_decode($result_string ));
```

For more information and idea, have a look at the [PHP Manual - Unserialize Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: Saw your additional code that you have added. So what you need to do is:  In your method **createUserObject** write the code as `$_SESSION['user'] = base64_encode(serialize($user));`

Comment: Now I get that error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class user could not be converted to string

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks